# How to pass parameters from one lambda to another in java?

Tags: java, aws-lambda

I want to invoke Lambda function A from another lambda function B with some parameters.

The following is the invoking lambda function.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements CommandLineRunner {
@Autowired
private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) {
    DCService dcService = LambdaInvokerFactory.builder().lambdaFunctionNameResolver(
            (method, lambdaFunction, lambdaInvokerFactoryConfig) -> "EventPlanDCFunction-Dev")
            .build(DCService.class);
    log.info("Response from DC service :: {}",dcService.getClass());
    String[] params = new String[]{"Subir has invoked"};
    dcService.run(params);
    SpringApplication.exit(context);
}
}
```

following is the code of `DCService.java` file.

```
public interface DCService {
@LambdaFunction(functionName = "DeliveryCycleLambdaHandler",
invocationType = InvocationType.Event)
void run(String... params);
}
```

The following is the code of the lambda function which I want to invoke.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements CommandLineRunner {
@Autowired
private ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
@Autowired
private DeliveryCycleService deliveryCycleService;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) {
    deliveryCycleService.printMessage(args[0]);
    SpringApplication.exit(context);
}
}
```

As you can see, I tried to pass the parameter by creating an array of String from the invoking method but I am getting `ArrayOutOFBoundException` in the other method meaning the parameter is not actually reaching the invoked method. If I do not pass parameter it works fine but for my use case, I need to pass parameter and invoke the method asynchronously.

**NOTE:** The lambdaHandle code is same for both of them. The following belongs to one of them.

```
@Slf4j
 public class DCInvokeHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DCInvokeHandler.class);
private volatile SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> handler;

@Override
public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream, Context context) throws IOException {
    if (handler == null) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (handler == null) {
                handler = initHandler();
            }
        }
    }

    handler.proxyStream(inputStream, outputStream, context);
}

private static SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler<AwsProxyRequest, AwsProxyResponse> initHandler() {
    try {
        return SpringBootLambdaContainerHandler.getAwsProxyHandler(Application.class, Env.getEnv().name());
    } catch (ContainerInitializationException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to start spring boot lambda handler", e);
        // if we fail here. We re-throw the exception to force another cold start
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not initialize Spring Boot application", e);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- This is the basic code to invoke another lambda from a lambda function.[aws sdk doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambdaClient.html#invoke-com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvokeRequest-)

```
try {


            InvokeRequest invokeRequest = new InvokeRequest();
            invokeRequest.setFunctionName(FunctionName);
            invokeRequest.setPayload(ipInput);


            returnDetails = byteBufferToString(
                    lambdaClient.invoke(invokeRequest).getPayload(),
                    Charset.forName("UTF-8"),logger);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            logger.log(e.getMessage());
        }
```

- To invoke the another lambda function asynchronously, set `InvocationType` to `Event`.[aws api docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/lambda/AWSLambdaClient.html#invoke-com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvokeRequest-)
- Following are the invocation type RequestResponse, Event, DryRun.
- RequestResponse (default) - Invoke the function synchronously. Keep the connection open until the function returns a response or times out. The API response includes the function response and additional data.
- Event - Invoke the function asynchronously. Send events that fail multiple times to the function's dead-letter queue (if it's configured). The API response only includes a status code.
- DryRun - Validate parameter values and verify that the user or role has permission to invoke the function.

Comment: So there is no way to send payload by using LambdaFunction annotation?

Comment: @Mistu4u you can send a payload form one lambda to another. In the above example `ipInput` is a json payload